# How to group a series of sibling elements with the same class in HTML?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I would like to process the following input HTML with XSLT 1.0 for the purpose of grouping a series of sibling elements.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p>A</p>
      <div class="case1">0</div>
      <div class="case1">1</div>
      <div class="case1">2</div>
      <p>B</p>
      <p>C</p>
      <div class="case2">3</div>
      <div class="case2">4</div>
      <p>D</p>
      <p>E</p>
      <div class="case1">5</div>
      <div class="case1">6</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The expected output is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p>A</p>
      <box class="case1">
        <p>0</p>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
      </box>
      <p>B</p>
      <p>C</p>
      <box class="case2">
        <p>3</p>
        <p>4</p>
      </box>
      <p>D</p>
      <p>E</p>
      <box class="case1">
        <p>5</p>
        <p>6</p>
      </box>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried writing the following XSL, but the `mode="inbox"` does not take effect, only the last `<xsl:template match="div[contains(@class, 'case')]" />` takes effect, causing the contents of the box to become empty.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- For the case of "case1". -->
  <xsl:template match="div[@class='case1'][not(preceding-sibling::*[1][@class='case1'])]">
    <box>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="inbox" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::div[@class='case1'][preceding-sibling::*[not(self::div[@class='case1'])][1]/following-sibling::div[@class='case1'][1] = current()]" mode="inbox" />
    </box>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="div[@class='case1']" mode="inbox">
    <p><xsl:apply-templates select="node()" /></p>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="div[@class='case1']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
<!-- For case2, similarly -->
```

If you don't mind, I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[@class]">
    <xsl:if test="not(@class=preceding-sibling::div[1]/@class)">
        <box class="{@class}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="inbox" />
        </box>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div" mode="inbox">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::div[1][@class=current()/@class]" mode="inbox" />
</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I wanted to accomplish.